# Magento 2 - What is the correct way to remove "Billing Agreements" tab from customer account?

Tags: magento2, module, layout, customer, billing-agreements

What is the correct and the easiest way to remove the "Billing Agreements" tab from frontend ?

The idea is just to hide the link so later if I need I could easily return it back.

To do this in Magento 1 we had to comment out in **billing_agreement.xml** module

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml`

How about in Magento 2?

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

1. Override this module in your theme:   `/vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`
2. I commented out the code
3. Clear the Cache and the the link is removed

Comment: no this is not the right way, copy that xml to your theme and make remove="true"

Comment: Don't edit the vendor files!

Comment: How to add billing agreements in my account sidebar links?